# Non expansive map in closed ball of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

let $c_{0}$ the set of all convergent sequences to zero,
we define the closed unit ball such that :

B={ x $\in$ $c_{0}$ :$\|x\|\leq 1$};

then we  define the map:
T:B $\rightarrow$ B by

T(x)=$(1,x_{1},x_{2},....)$

T is non expansive mapping and no has fixed point

I want to find sequence  $(x_{n})$ $\in$ B such that

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }$$ ||x_{n}-Tx||=0$

Comment: Could you clarify which norm you are using?

Comment: ||x||= $\sup_{n}||x_{n}||$

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by $x$ in $lim \Vert x_n - Tx \Vert $? It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: $T(x)=(1,x_{1},x_{2},....) $ $x_{n} \in c_{0}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $0\leq a_k<1$ be any sequence of real numbers on the unit interval which converges to 1.
Then define $x_k=(a_k^0,a_k^1,a_k^2...)$.

Then $||x_k-Tx_k||=1-a$ which tends to zero for large k.

Answer (score 0):

I want sequence $x_{n} $ $\in$ B $\subseteq$ $c_{0}$

Comment: Do you find the answer because I need it.